# How to find the cdf of $U=y-x$

Tags: probability, statistics

The random variables x and y have the probability density functions $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=4e^{-2(x+y)}$. How do I find the probability density functions of $U=y-x

I have tried solve by convolution theorem by letting the limits from $0$ to $-u$ in the $y$-axis and from $0$ to $y-u$ in the x-axis. But according to the calculation I have done I don't get the provided answer:

$$(4 e^{2 u} )[(u \ e^{4u} )/2-u/4-e^{4 u} /10+1/16]$$

Please help.

Comment: Is $U=x+y$ or $y-x$?

Comment: Here is mathjax tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user103828 it is supposed to be U=y-y

Comment: What are the limits of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The limits stated in the questions are such that X>0,y>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supports are $X\in[0;\infty), Y\in[0;\infty)$

So choosing the bounds for the convolution of the sum of the variables is easy.

$\begin{align}
\text{Let: }\quad U&=X+Y
\\[1ex]  \therefore &\quad X\in[0;U]\wedge Y=U-X 
\\[2ex]
f_U(u) & = \int_0^u f_{X,Y}(x, u-x)\operatorname dx
\end{align}$

---

The "trick" with the bounds for the convolution of the difference is that whether we integrate with respect to $X$ or $Y$ depends on the sign of $V$.

$\begin{align}
\text{Let: }\quad V&=X-Y
\\[1ex] \therefore & \quad V\in[0;\infty)\to X\in [V;\infty)\wedge Y=X-V
\\[1ex]  & \quad V\in(-\infty;0) \to Y\in[-V;\infty)\wedge X=V+Y
\\[2ex]
f_V(v)
 & = \int_v^\infty f_{X,Y}(x, x-v)\operatorname d x\;\mathbf 1_{[0;\infty)}(v) + \int_{-v}^\infty f_{X,Y}(v+y,y)\operatorname d y\; \mathbf 1_{(-\infty;0)}(v)
\end{align}$

Comment: thanx alot, but would you try with V=Y-X

Comment: @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA  Symmetry.

Comment: How do I get the pdf for U=y-x?

Comment: @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA Just swap the symbols in the answer given, by symmetry; because $X$ and $Y$ are identically and independently distributed.